# How to add rectangles to image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have an image, and a set of rectangles to overlay over the image.

For example-

Image = `https://picsum.photos/200/300`

Rectangles = `{'top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;'},  {'top: 15%; left: 20%; width: 20%; height: 40%;'}, {'top: 5%; left: 40%; width: 10%; height: 10%;'},`

The percentages are relative to the image.

I need help writing HTML/CSS that will take the image, overlay each rectangle and make the rectangles red outline with transparent red interior.

I also need a solution that preserves the aspect ratio of the image, whilst making sure the rectangles are placed relative to the image, not any containers the image might sit in.

It should also make sure that regardless of the monitor size, container size, that the rectangles are overlaying correctly placed relative to the image.

The solution needs to replicable so I can use it for different images, I can't use any other languages, and I have no knowledge of the aspect ratio so the solution needs to be independent of that.

Here is the code I have so far made using tools and my own tweaks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* Set the image as the background */
    .image-container {
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 75%; /* Adjust this value to maintain the aspect ratio of the image */
    }
    
    /* Define the rectangles using absolute positioning */
    .rectangle {
      position: absolute;
      border: 2px solid red;
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Light shade of transparent red */
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure the rectangles appear above the image */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='image-container'>
    <!-- Define the rectangles using the provided coordinates -->
    <div class='rectangle' style='top: 5%; left: 40%; width: 10%; height: 10%;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='top: 15%; left: 20%; width: 20%; height: 40%;'></div>
    <div class='rectangle' style='top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;'></div>
    <!-- Add more rectangles as needed -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It gets me 90% there, but I'm not sure about the aspect ratio part. In the `.image-container` this solution needs to be fed a `%` for the padding in order to make sure the height preserves the aspect ratio.

Since I won't know the aspect ratio this doesn't work for me.

Is it not possible to say something like:

"Here is the image, don't worry about the aspect ratio, just make the container size the same size as the image, adding scroll bars if you need to and draw the rectangles on relative to the image only".

Please help.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't know the aspect ratio of the image? Someone does else they wouldnt have been able to give those % positions of the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with any image is to get the width of the image, because the image you are using is much shorter than the width of the div, and the browser will think you mean the whole div, not just the image that you added. Note that you added `background-repeat: no-repeat`, so it wouldn't be the other parts of the div. So you should add some javascript that gets the width of the image and make it the width of .image-container, like this:

```
function manageContainer(container) {
    let image_name = container.getElementsByClassName("src")[0].text();
    let img = document.createElement("img");/* Creating image */
    img.src = `url({image_name})`;
    container.style.width = img.naturalWidth;
    container.appendChild(img);
}
document.getElementsByClassName("image-container").forEach(manageContainer);
```

And to get the source of the image, you can add a hidden  element somewhere in the div instead of putting it in the css. (Note that if you don't add it, it will throw an error.)